# Oracle Linked Server in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to set up a linked server from a SQL Server 2017 instance to an Oracle database.  I have found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916563/ssis-ora-12638-visual-studio-2017) where the question is for Visual Studio and the answer was to install ODAC, but the link provided is to a 32 bit ODAC specifically for VS2017.

Other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444576/linking-oracle-with-sql-server) I have found suggest installing the full Oracle Server.  I just need the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider for a LinkedServer on SQL Server.   I have the TNSNAMES file and everything and have accomplished this before, but only by installing the full Oracle Server, but that feels like overkill.  What is the minimum I would need to install and configure on my SQL Server box to accomplish this?  This feels like it should be very easy to accomplish, but for some reason it is not for me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after several hours I figured this out myself.  I needed to install the [64 bit ODAC components from the Oracle Website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).

Once I had that I needed to unzip and execute the install.bat batch process from command prompt, running cmd.exe ***as an administrator***

```
d:\oracle\install.bat all c:\oracle odac
```

*Note above, you can download your ODAC to anywhere, for me it was a directory I created in d:\oracle... and you can install to anywhere, but I think c:\oracle is common.

Once I did that, I needed to add c:\oracle and c:\oracle\bin to my PATH environment variable.

So this was quite simple in the end.  Hope this helps someone else trying to navigate the same challenge.